# ini_set not working

Tags: php

Here is the matter:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('safe_mode', '0');
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', '1');
ini_set('allow_url_include', '1');
print_r(ini_get_all());
```

And I get:

```
Array(
    [allow_url_fopen] => Array
        (
            [global_value] => 1
            [local_value] => 1
            [access] => 4
        )

    [allow_url_include] => Array
        (
            [global_value] => 
            [local_value] => 
            [access] => 4
        )
```

Why I cannot set that variable within the php ini_set function? The directive is specified as PHP_INI_ALL then it can be defined within the ini_set() function!
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**`display_errors`**

may be set at runtime (with `ini_set()`), but it won't have any affect if the script has fatal errors. This is because the desired runtime action does not get executed.

Use `ini_set('display_errors','Off');`

**`safe_mode`**

This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0. This directive belongs to `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` and Cannot be set via `ini_set()`

**`allow_url_include`**

Use `ini_set('allow_url_include', 'On');`

**`allow_url_fopen`**

This directive belongs to `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` and Cannot be set via `ini_set()`

Comment: What is the alternative of `ini_set()` in php5.3? If you dont have access to apache config files. The only option you have is to include in your code.

Comment: dude you are a legend, thanks very much, it has been bothering me all day.

Answer (score 8):

These variables cannot be changed within a user script. The `access` value means:

```
PHP_INI_SYSTEM    4          Entry can be set in php.ini or httpd.conf
```

You can try to set it in `.htaccess`:

```
php_value  allow_url_include 1
```

Comment: but here they say the opposite, it is an ini_set_all directive! http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Comment: no, it is not ! they says that allow_url_fopen is PHP_INI_SYSTEM

Comment: oh the first one you mean: but that variable is already on. It is set on true as you can see, isn't it...?

Comment: ok: what abut the allow_url_include directive? that's my real point.

Comment: can you try to set it in php.ini or .htaccess ?

Comment: I'm flagging green because he answered first, thanks!!! I can't change the htaccess :(

Answer (score 1):

My answer might be off-topic but I almost always come back to this question via Google when my `ini_set` calls are not working. Sharing my case might help others to solve an issue with `ini_set` more quickly.

So, in my case `display_errors` is disabled but PHP still displays the errors in the browser although I enabled `log_errors` and set `error_log` to `C:\Windows\Temp\PHP_error.log`.

First impression is always that *ini_set is not working* BUT it might be a permission issue. If PHP cannot access the log file then it will simply send the errors to the browser.

**Solution:** make sure PHP has the permission to access and write the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting boolean values instead of 0 or 1?

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('safe_mode', false);
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', true);
ini_set('allow_url_include', true);
print_r(ini_get_all());
```

Or try this:

```
ini_set('allow_url_include', 'on');
```

Answer (score 0):

allow_url_fopen can't be modified by ini_set. It's because some ini statements has to be declared in an ini file only.

Comment: nope: here the available ini set directive, is not specified as an only php.ini directive!  http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Comment: what? i'm reading this by now: allow_url_include "0" PHP_INI_ALL  PHP_INI_SYSTEM in PHP 5. Available since PHP 5.2.0. What am I missing in the php.net file? :(

Comment: oh no i got itttttt, sorryyyyyyyyyyY!!! the second columns says the change in the php version!! sorry ;(

Answer (score -1):

if you get this message in zabbix interface `"ini_set(): Use of mbstring.internal_encoding is deprecated"`

simply go to file vi /usr/local/share/zabbix/include/locales.inc.php and commet the line

```
#       ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding', 'UTF-8');"
```

restart `httpd` & `zabbix-server` daemons , then try.. thats it.!