# file_get_contents in codeigniter on shared host

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my code igniter project in WAMP I'm able to do this and it works:

`file_get_contents('C:\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\controllers\calendarmonth.sql');`

I can't seem to figure out which path to use when it's on my live shared hosting site.

When I do

`file_get_contents(base_url() .'application/controllers/Calendarmonth.sql');`

I get "*HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden*"

Comment: how would we know your file structure?

Comment: The file I'm trying to get is in public_html\application\controllers , sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Most shared hosts block remote content in PHP.

Comment: @David Place this `Calendarmonth.sql` file outside application folder.

Comment: well then use that path? its not in the examples you tried (are you really hosting on windows/)

Comment: something like FCPATH constant will be what you want. That will give you the full path to your main application.

Comment: On live run `var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));` If you get 'Off / false' then you won't be able to use it.

Comment: @Spartan that did the trick, thank you again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move  the `Calendarmonth.sql` file outside application folder.

If exist set [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) in php

---

**FYI**

**application/controller** path will secure always. So if adding external file add to outside of application. Application root is always accessible.

---

**Links**

1. [`ini_set` not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12618546/4595675)

Comment: @David Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a post at:
[base_url() function not working in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter)

The best answer there should probably a fix for you as well. You need to enable base_url() first in your configuration.

Comment: Not related to the question